# static array of char not filled

Tags: c, unix, static

I want to fill an array of char, one by one, so I am using the above code for testing, and the final output of "str" will always be the first char entered instead of all char, whats wrong ?

```
void gime_char(char c)
{
    static *str;
    static i;

    if(i == 0)
        str = malloc(sizeof(*str) * 10);
    if(c == 'X')
    {
        printf("full str:%s\n", str);
    }
    printf("c == %c\n", c);
    str[i] = c;
    printf("d == %d\n", i);
    i++;
}

int main()
{
    char c;

    while(c != 'X')
    {
        c = getchar();
        gime_char(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure "static i;" is initialized to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `static *str` is `static int *str`, but a string consists of `char`s. So now your string does not end up being stored with the characters adjacent to one another as you would expect, because each element of `str` has the size of `int` (probably 4 bytes), not that of `char`.

This part of the code should be fixed by specifying the type as `static char *str`. Once you fix that, there will be another problem when printing `str` without terminating it with a NUL character (`'\0'`).

Comment: do you know why it still print the first charact ? since he interpret it at int *str

Comment: @Saxtheowl You mean why it prints the first char even though the type is `int`? It so happens that on your platform the lowest byte of the `int` is stored first in memory, and the other bytes are zero since you only assigned a single byte, so the first two bytes happen to be your first char and zero, which makes up a valid single-character string in C. (Note that this depends on byte order.)

Comment: (I also recommend increasing the warning levels of your compiler; it should have warned when passing `str` to `printf` with the format `%s`.)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a type in the definition of `i`, and the type in the definition of `str` is incomplete: you say “pointer” (with the `*` character) but you don't say to what. For historical reasons, if you omit a type, the compiler assumes you meant `int`; this is deprecated, and good compilers warn about this.

Since you effectively wrote `int *str`, the memory layout looks something like this after entering `hello` (this is machine-dependent, but this is a pretty typical case):

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----
| 'h' |   0 |   0 |   0 | 'e' |   0 |   0 |   0 | 'l' |   0 | ...
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----
 ^                       ^                       ^
 |                       |                       |
str                    str+1                   str+2
```

Each small cell is one byte (which corresponds to one character). Four cells make up one `int`. The line

```
str[i] = c;
```

writes one `int` into `str`. For example, when `c` is `'h'`, which has the numerical value 104, the number 104 is written into the `int` object `str[0]`, which is represented as the four-byte sequence `{104, 0, 0, 0}`. This happens again for the next character, which is written in the next `int`-sized slot in the array, meaning 4 bytes further.

In the line

```
printf("full str:%s\n", str);
```

you print `str` as a string. In a string, the first zero byte marks the end of the string. So you see the string `"h"`.

Your machine is [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian). Exercise: what would you see on a big-endian machine?

The fix is to declare the types properly.

You should also initialize your variables. `static` variables are initialized to 0 anyway, but it's clearer if you do it explicitly. The variable `c` is not `static`, so it starts out containing whichever value was there before in memory; this could happen to be `'X'`, so you must initialize it explicitly.

Additionally, you need to make sure that the string is terminated by a zero byte before printing it. The `static` keyword ensures that the `str` variable is initialized to a null pointer, but the space that the pointer points to is allocated by `malloc` and contains whatever was there before.

```
void            gime_char(char c)
{
  static        char *str;         /* <<<< */
  static        int i;             /* <<<< */

  if(i == 0)
    str = malloc(sizeof(*str) * 10);
  if(c == 'X')
    {
      str[i] = 0;                 /* <<<< */
      printf("full str:%s\n", str);
    }
  printf("c == %c\n", c);
  str[i] = c;
  printf("d == %d\n", i);
  i++;
}

int             main()
{
  char          c = 0;             /* <<<< */

  while(c != 'X')
    {
      c = getchar();
      gime_char(c);
    }
  return 0;                        /* <<<< */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Advices :

- Check that malloc didn't return an error
- i is not initialize
- Type of *str is wrong (static char *str)
- Before using %s you have to add a '\0' at the end of your string.

Comment: i dont need to be initialized since is a static, no ?

Comment: @Saxtheowl ...but it is better to read for everyone else (knowing against seeing)

Answer (score 0):

I would say your problem comes from fact that you declare `static *str;`.
You declare it with out specifying the type! Compilers pass with, with a warning that this implies an `int`. So basically you end up with a static pointer to `int`. Which is not meant to store ANSI strings.

Later you allocate space for the buffer (I suppose) with `str = malloc(sizeof(*str) * 10);`. This is also wrong, because you allocate space for 10 *pointers to str*.

You want to work with characters.

```
static char *str;
if(i == 0)
  str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
```

Also you should initialize the string to zeros as it is almost certain you will get some garbage there and ANSI string is expected to be `NULL` terminated. Preferably `i` too but compilers initialize variables on stack.